# How to compare data of a table between two database in java, example product_type table of DEV and UAT database

Tags: java, oracle

I have to write a java program that has two compare a table of two database instance having the same schema.
It is mainly to identify development changes.

```
Database: DEVDB     Database: UATDB
Schema: RAPP        Schema: RAPP
Table: PRODUCT_TYPE  Table: PRODUCT_TYPE


TABLE COLUMNS:
PROD_TYPE_ID
TYPE
CLASS
```

Now assuming the column structure remains constant, I could add new product types on my DEVDB or i could change the class or type value for any of the existing rows on the DEVDB table.
My program has to run and compare these two instance and identify if anything new row has been added or any of the existing values of a existing row is modified.

Comment: How large are these tables? # of rows?

Comment: A maximum of 5000 rows.